# Getting API Call Request Limit

Tags: excel, vba, odata

I am trying to pull data from a web API into Excel using VBA. For the time being I am writing to a JSON file. Code is as follows:

```
Sub get_data(up_http, down_http)
    Dim xmlhttp: Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")

    xmlhttp.Open "get", up_http, False
    xmlhttp.send

    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Dim newfile: Set newfile = fso.createtextfile(down_http, True)

    newfile.write (xmlhttp.responseText)
    newfile.Close

    Set newfile = Nothing
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
    get_data _
        "https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/TaxInvoice/get?apikey=
    {xxxxxxxx}&companyid=12345&includeDetail=true&includeCustomerDetails=true&$orderby=Created%20desc", _
        "C:\temp\tmp.json"
End Sub
```

This all works. The provider of the API has set a limit of 100 calls per minute, but that have confirmed that I can use the ODATA Skip function to get around the limit. Can anyone assist with how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2010/02/16/consuming-odata-with-office-vba-part-i/

Comment: Did you mean [Skip System Query Option ($skip)](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) ?